# Works with gcc, not with Arduino. error: taking address of temporary array

Tags: c++, array, pointer, gcc

I need to hard code 8 byte addresses into char arrays of length 8. This must be done many places in my code (in function scope), so I have tried to come up with a one-liner. The following works perfectly in C when compiling with gcc.

```
char a[8];

void cpaddr(char target[], char *source) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
        target[i] = source[i];
}

int main() {
    char b[] = {0x00, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA2, 0x7D};
    cpaddr(a, b);

    // line below does not compile with Arduino IDE
    cpaddr(a, (char[]) {0x00, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA2, 0x7D});
}
```

When compiling on Arduino the last line, which is the one-liner I was aiming for, does not compile. It gives:

```
/home/bob/Desktop/ate/Ate.ino: In function 'int main()':
Ate:101: error: taking address of temporary array
cpaddr(a, (char[]) {0x00, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA2, 0x7D});
^
exit status 1
taking address of temporary array
```

What is the problem here, that apparently is not a problem with gcc?

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried 
void cpaddr(char target[], const char *source)

Comment: I tried your exact code with g++ (and gcc) version 4.8.4 and got the exact same error message you got.

Comment: I'm using 4.9.3. Screenshot of result: http://i.imgur.com/2RJbGwg.png

Comment: `( type[] ){val, ues}` is not a valid way to create a temporary in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458883/using-array-init-list-as-temporary-in-c11#comment26614881_18163000 The solution is to typedef it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite right, using that kind of syntax is not allowed. It's a bit of a pain, but it's ok since there is an alternative method - kind of a "trick" if you will.

That trick is to use a string, not an array. After all, a string is just an array, it's just handled slightly differently by the compiler.

Instead of using `{...}` use `"..."` and use the hexadecimal character escape sequence `\xNN`, such as:

```
cpaddr(a, "\x00\x10\xFF\xCA\x00\x00\xA2\x7D");
```

You could even lose your custom function and use a standard library function - `memcpy()`:

```
memcpy(a, "\x00\x10\xFF\xCA\x00\x00\xA2\x7D", 8);
```

On the 8-bit AVRs you can save RAM by using the progmem variant and the `F()` macro:

```
memcpy_P(a, F("\x00\x10\xFF\xCA\x00\x00\xA2\x7D"), 8);
```

Comment: I think that it should be PSTR() instead of F(). F() is a very special Arduino String hack.

Comment: F() just imposes a type to PSTR() for overloading. You can use either.

Comment: Because of the type you cannot use F() directly without a cast. The compiler will say "cannot convert 'const __FlashStringHelper*' to 'const char*'".

Comment: Mine didn't. It compiled perfectly fine. I always test before posting code. It's not a cast, it's a reinterpret_cast.

Comment: But apparently not on memcpy_P as it takes whatever, i.e. const void*.

Comment: In any case F() is part of the "black-listed" String class. That should be enough to use PSTR() instead :)

Comment: This is true ;)

Comment: No it isn't. The define `#define F(string_literal) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(PSTR(string_literal)))` is in WString.h, however there is no connection between `F()` and the `String` class except that the `String` class *uses* it in certain cases (as does the `Print` class). In fact as you can see from the `#define` saying to use `PSTR()` instead doesn't make any sense. `F()` *already uses* `PSTR()`. It's purpose is just to create a new type that can be used to detect if a string is in PROGMEM or RAM. That's all.

Comment: @NickGammon Isn't that mainly for overloading, like I mentioned above? ;)

Comment: Er, yes it turns `# define PSTR(s) (__extension__({static const char __c[] PROGMEM = (s); &__c[0];}))
` (which is still type `const char []`) into another type, which then assists with overloading. So I agree that (after casting) they would be the same thing. However neither PSTR nor F() are "part of the black-listed String class". I see no objection to using F() here. In fact your suggestion would save RAM compared to what I did in my reply, although mine is probably "cleaner" in that you aren't throwing in a `memcpy_P` (and making sure you get the length right).

Answer (score 1):

See [Using array init list as temporary in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458883/using-array-init-list-as-temporary-in-c11)

You can solve it by using `const`. This compiles:

```
char a[8];

void cpaddr(char target[], const byte *source) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
        target[i] = source[i];
}

int main() {
    byte b[] = {0x00, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA2, 0x7D};
    cpaddr(a, b);
    cpaddr(a, (const byte[]) {0x00, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA2, 0x7D});
}
```

Note I had to change your array from `char` to `byte` because I was getting (valid) warnings that things like 0xCA don't fit into a char.

Comment: As Majenko said, `memcpy` would be better than doing a byte-by-byte copy.

Comment: I hate it when people use non-standard arduino specific types like byte, when there is a perfectly good and standard uint8_t available...

Comment: As explained in the very thread you linked, `( type[] ){val, ues}` is not a valid way to create a temporary in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458883/using-array-init-list-as-temporary-in-c11#comment26614881_18163000 The solution is to typedef it.

Comment: Recent versions of the IDE use C++11, so whether or not it is valid in C++ doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fix it?

"Char []" shouldn't compile under c. It is just invalid.

You can use string, cast to char * . or just another pointer as you did already.